# Poisson process. How to solve?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose that people immigrate to a territory according to a Poisson process with a
$\lambda =$ rate of 1 per day.

What is the expected time until the tenth immigrant arrives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The waiting time between events has **exponential** distribution with parameter $\lambda$. Let $X_1$ be the waiting time until the first event, $X_2$ be the waiting time between the first event and the second, and so on.

Let $Y=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_{10}$. We want $E(Y)$. By the linearity of expectation, we have
$$E(Y)=E(X_1+\cdots+X_{10})=E(X_1)+\cdots +E(X_{10})=\frac{10}{\lambda}.$$

Answer (score 1):

If $N(t)$ is your poisson process, and $S_k$ are the interarrival epochs, you are asking what is $\mathbb{E}[S_{10}]$

But that is $= 10/\lambda = 10$. Thus 10 days.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming nothing else happens on the island: 10 days

EDIT: For a Poisson rv with parameter $\lambda$ $\mathbf{E}X= \lambda$, and in the Poisson process arrivals are independent, hence you have 10 iid rvs. Also, as Andre Nichloas pointed out, the time between events in a Poisson process (interarrival times) is exponentially distributed with mean $\frac{1}{\lambda}$.

Comment: You might want to add a little more detail to your answer to make it clearer to the OP. Regards